# How to delete N files of X type from Y subfolders from a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, file-io, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a windows batch file that can delete files from subdirectories.  I would rather not hard code the directory structure in, so I can use this process with other projects.

- I need to delete files of X type,
- I have the parent folder `C:\MyProject`,
- There are Y subfolders `C:\MyProject\?`,
- There are N files to delete.

Is there a quick `del` (of type) function I am simply missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually you can use the standard del command:

```
c:
cd MyProject
del /S *.type
```

Where type is the extension you want to delete and the /S parameter will check in all subfolders of MyProject.

Comment: Funny thing, after years of programming I thought this will be somekind of loop with "if"s and stuff...

Comment: please note that this will also delete any files with a matching sub-string in the beginning of its extension. For example `del /S *.doc` deletes both `.doc` and `.docx` file-types.

Answer (score 1):

If the del command didn't have the /S flag to delete recursively, I'd use AWK to do something like this (you'd need the UNIX tools for Windows):

```
dir MyProject\*.* /ad /s /b | gawk "{print \"del \\\"\" $0 \"\\*.type\\\"\";}" | cmd
```

My 2 cents, in case you ever need to do something similar (applying a program to all files of X type in all subfolders) with a command that lacks a recursive flag.